# Draw state transition diagram for identifying a sequence of bits

Tags: flipflop, state-machines

A state transition diagram has to be drawn for the following scenario. (Later it has to be implemented using D flipflops)

Scenario:-

A sequential machine to resolve a 4-bit security code. The code is "1010" and it is sent to the resolving circuitry as a sequence of bits. The output of the detector should be raised to 1 if and only if the correct code is detected.

It says the code is sent as a sequence of bits and I tried to come up with the state transition diagram as below.

[image]

Is it correct? Or is there something missing?

Comment: It's missing an accept indicator and the fact that the code must be 4 bits long.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams   How to check for the length of the code?

Answer (score 1):

For an input `1` the output will be `1`. As for any code ending with `1`. So it is incorrect. As a general rule - for detection of a sequence with length `N` you need N states for Moore machine or `N-1` for Mealy machine (your case).